# Some illogical errors

Tags: android, xml

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':markushiUI')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

> Information:Gradle tasks [:materialTabs:generateDebugSources, :materialTabs:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :materialTabs:mockableAndroidJar, :markushiUI:generateDebugSources, :markushiUI:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :markushiUI:mockableAndroidJar, :videoDown:generateDebugSources, :videoDown:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :videoDown:mockableAndroidJar]
>       C:\Users\MEGHA.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.2.0.aar\9161f81ae777eacf49e3e76b2db3945d\res\values\values.xml
>       Error:(1044, 5) error: style attribute 'android:attr/backgroundDim' not found.
>       Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
>       Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
>       Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse not found.
>       E:\client\VideoDown\videoDown\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
>       Error:(1485) style attribute 'android:attr/backgroundDim' not found.
>       Error:resource android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored not found.
>       Error:failed linking references.
>       Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':videoDown:processDebugResources'.
>
> Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s
>   Information:11 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: If you can add also the build.gradle for the module markushiUI. Most probably the problem is there

Comment: I didnt understand. Please explaon

Comment: I changed my answer. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your "third module" gradle file this way:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.videodownloader"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':materialTabs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.1.0.jar')
}
```

I had your same error with your configuration. After I applied this changes I could build the project.

**UPDATED**

Comment: Post your build.gradle file please

Comment: Which one Project one or module one?

Comment: The module one for sure. If you want also the project one.